# What does "robbin" mean here?

Tags: word-meaning, slang, apostrophe

[Doctor Who: The Stone Rose](https://www.fanfiction.net/s/9187065/1/The-Stone-Rose)

> 'What? It can't be that bad, can it? You've not been **robbin**' it or
>   something? Or you been seeing one of the girls in the gift shop and
>   you don't wanna tell me about it?" He frowned a no, but still looked
>   sheepish. "Come on Mickey. Spit it out" Peter said. Mickey put back
>   his shoulders, attempting a bit of bravado. "Well..I've been doing
>   this volunteer stuff. You know, kids and that."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> You've not been **robbin'** it or something?

In other words:

> You haven't been **robbing** it or something?

As a representation of speech, an apostrophe is often used to replace one or more letters of a word. It's especially common to see it used to replace the *g* in the *-ing* form of verbs: *robbin'*, *goin'*, *seein'*, *tryin'*, *cryin'*, and so on.

Comment: I see. But I don't see an apostrophe is much more save-labour than a 'g'.

Comment: @zhang You're right, it isn't. But it's easier to *pronounce* the word without the *g*. Writing it with an apostrophe is just an attempt to transcribe what's been spoken into words. (It's a visual representation of what's said.)